# Prevent Microsoft Word from reducing image resolution when publishing *.docx as web page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, html, vml

When saving as a web page from Word (365), is there any chance of having the images on the web page thus created in high resolution?

Although the maximum resolution for images is set in all conceivable places in Word:

[image: Word Web Options and Image Compression]

[image: Word Advanced Options -> Image Size and Quality]

...the images still appear in a much lower resolution on the web page.

In Word itself the images still appear in high resolution even if not the *.docx, but the saved web page is reopened in Word. Only when the web page is viewed in the browser, the images appear with a much lower resolution.

Has this problem ever been solved anywhere in the world?

I'm afraid not so, as the [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rely%20on%20VML%22%20%22low%20resolution%22) that should best illuminate the problem returns only two useless hits.

Also, the images are downsampled by Word only for "old browsers". The [VML code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language#Microsoft_Outlook_HTML_email_rendering) of the website created by Word and intended for "modern browsers" always contains the images in original resolution.

[image: Word Web Options]

However, the time of "modern browsers" with VML support feels like it was 20 years ago. Current browsers ignore the VML code completely.

The website is updated almost daily, and must be edited in Word for certain reasons.

Comment: Odd that *current* Word of Office 365 has option to target **Internet Explorer 6** ! If you set another target, is resolution improved?

Comment: Internet Explorer 6 is THE LATEST browser in those settings! That is the problem...

Comment: Though you do state MS Word is the approved editor, have you *tested* LibreOffice Writer, which has pretty much the same capabilities, and *might* better handle export to HTML (or not)?

Comment: Good point....... I haven't actually. Will do. This is however a corporate environment, so I'd have to see if using LO could be a viable option.

Comment: AFAICS Word rarely leaves an image @as is@ when saving as HTML - one example here was saved at around 2500x1800 pixels or some such, but the original was more like 6000x4000. Maybe there's a maximum and as long as you don't exceed it you can get an unchanged resolution, but that's difficult to test.

Comment: That would not affect me, since my file's images are at most about one megapixel in size

Comment: Unfortunately, Libre Office fails catastrophically when saving my Word file as HTML. While the Word file itself displays moderately okay in Libre Office, the file saved as HTML comes out as utter garbage.

Comment: Has this been fixed? Because I complained about it all over the place during 2023?
When image compression is set to "High Fidelity" and "Do not compress images in file", Word doesn't seem to change the image resolution anymore now? It definitely didn't do that before, at least not until the time of my OP above. Does anyone know anything about what happened?